# MS Excel - obtaining and presenting results by combining logical operators, sums, pivot tables, and forms

Tags: excel, report, logical-operators

Before I present the question, I would like to state that I have spent time researching for a solution for this problem, with partial luck.

*So, here's the scenario:*
There are X number of users, using Y number of products.  Each user may use one or more products.  Some of the users work from home and others from the office.

e.g.

```
ID  Office  Home Dept    P1 P2 P3   
1   loc1    1    dep1    1  1  0
2   loc1    0    dep1    0  0  1
3   loc2    1    dep1    1  1  1
4   loc4    1    dep2    1  0  1
5   loc3    0    dep2    1  1  0            
6   loc3    0    dep1    1  1  0                    
7   loc1    0    dep3    1  0  0
```

*What I want to achieve:*
I would like to calculate and present, for various combinations of products, the number of users in common and the total number of users.  I know that I can use the logical functions 'or' and 'and' to determine 'union' and 'intersection', and calculate a column sum to get the total number of users and number of users in common.  However, I would like to be able to select various combinations of products without creating a new formula each time; something with check-boxes.

*What I want to present:*
As for the presentation of the data, would I be able to create something useful via a pivot table, or should I look at custom forms, which include check-boxes for P1, P2, P3, ...?  Any hints and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
amx13

Comment: Why not just use a pivot table? You can filter that according to your needs.

Comment: Tried the pivot table... I was not able to calculate / obtain the number of users in common and the total number of users.  Perhaps you can suggest the pivot table items to give me a better idea.  Thx

Comment: I would start by "de-pivoting" your Product columns to give you more flexibility in how you can use pivot tables on the data. ie. instead of having separate P1, P2, etc columns, add a "ProductId" and "Use" column and use the data in the "P" columns to populate those new columns.